# Incrementing assembly version in CruiseControl.NET for ClickOnce publish

Tags: clickonce, cruisecontrol.net

Although this seems like other questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488918/how-to-sync-publish-version-to-assembly-version-in-a-net-clickonce-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721609/clickonce-same-publish-version-but-assembly-version-different-update-not-happenihttp://)), I have a problem that is not quite addressed by these answers.

I have an application that is deployed as a ClickOnce application, and I can publish it from Visual Studio 2010, which increments the assembly version correctly. When I do the same in CC.NET, then how do I increment the version and then check this back in (if I need to do that), so that the versions are correct the next build ?

Thanks in advance

**Update**

The build labeller looks like this ..

```
  <labeller type="assemblyVersionLabeller">
    <build>-1</build>
    <incrementOnFailure>True</incrementOnFailure>
    <major>1</major>
    <minor>1</minor>
    <revision>-1</revision>
  </labeller>
```

How do I get that value into the MSBuild for publishing ?

Comment: do you want the svn version number in the build labellar.

Comment: I what the build number that CC.NET generates to be used by the assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this thing

```
< labeller type="defaultlabeller">

  < prefix>2.2.0.< /prefix>

  < incrementOnFailure>False< /incrementOnFailure>

< /labeller>
```

There is an interesting post on this [here](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/02/23/Synchronize-assembly-version-with-CC.NET-build-number-with-NAnt.aspx)